# "in dignity" VS "with dignity"

Tags: prepositions

> 1. The Sustainable Development Goals (SDG), adopted by the United Nations in 2016, all have one goal: by 2030, all inhabitants of planet Earth should be able to live **in** dignity.
> 2. The Sustainable Development Goals (SDG), adopted by the United Nations in 2016, all have one goal: by 2030, all inhabitants of planet Earth should be able to live **with** dignity.

I am wondering which preposition is the right one here.

Comment: Both prepositions are fine, and I don't think there's any significant semantic or syntactic difference between them. But it's worth noting that until about a century ago, [***live with dignity*** was far more common than ***live in dignity***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+live+in+dignity%2Cto+live+with+dignity&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20live%20in%20dignity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20live%20with%20dignity%3B%2Cc0). I'd guess the latter has gained traction by analogy with ***live in peace***, where we never use ***with***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really go wrong with *"with"*. As FumbleFingers mentioned in their comment, both prepositions can be used, and using *"in"* won't change the main essence or meaning of the sentence - the focus will remain on *"dignity"*.

---

**Google results: *"with"* is more common in AmE**

Google Ngram shows both [*"to live **in** dignity"* and *"to live **with** dignity"*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to%20live%20in%20dignity%2Cto%20live%20with%20dignity&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20live%20in%20dignity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20live%20with%20dignity%3B%2Cc0) were commonly used between 1950 and 1980. Since 1980, *"with"* has been used more often in that phrase. This trend holds true for [*"live in/with dignity"*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=live%20in%20dignity%2Clive%20with%20dignity&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clive%20in%20dignity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clive%20with%20dignity%3B%2Cc0).

There is a difference in the usage between [AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to%20live%20in%20dignity%2Cto%20live%20with%20dignity&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20live%20in%20dignity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20live%20with%20dignity%3B%2Cc0) and [BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to%20live%20in%20dignity%2Cto%20live%20with%20dignity&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20live%20in%20dignity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20live%20with%20dignity%3B%2Cc0). *"To live **with** dignity"* has **always** been more popular and commonly used in AmE. In BrE, both were commonly used from 1900 to 1990; their usage appears to be have been very close until 2004 (check out the Ngrams).

Note that the numbers of google hits on those phrases don't really say anything meaningful (*in* = 209 and *with* = 229 after jumping to the last page).

---

**Dictionaries: *"with"* wins hands down**

When I looked up "dignity" on a few free online collocations dictionaries, I found *"with"* as the only preposition suggested.

None of the examples for "dignity" in Cambridge dictionary has *"in"* as a preposition. This holds true for Collins and Merriam-Webster as well.

---

**Other concerns: just some observations - feel free to ignore**

(1) From the few sources ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sustainable_Development_Goals), [2](https://sustainabledevelopment.un.org/?menu=1300), and [3](https://www.un.org/sustainabledevelopment/development-agenda/)) I skimmed through, it appears that the SDGs were set or *adopted* by the members in 2015 (they became official in 2016). You might want to look into that.

(2) One thing that may bother some people is the following:

> The Sustainable Development **Goals** ... all have one **goal** ...

It is not wrong, but it sounds a little unidiomatic. But that is just a personal thing.

(3) I am not sure about your line of reasoning (because I don't know the content). Be sure to explain how the goals all relate to "dignity". I tried to make the link but failed to do so for some of the goals.

> *"... a universal call to action to **end poverty, protect the planet and ensure that all people enjoy peace and prosperity** by 2030."* - [UNDP](https://www.undp.org/content/undp/en/home/sustainable-development-goals.html)

I personally think "dignity" is not the appropriate word to describe the quoted material. Again, ignore this if you are able to make the link.

Comment: +1. "other concerns"?

Comment: @EddieKal Thanks, I just made some additional comments.

Answer (score 1):

**Dignity** is a noun, meaning "*the state or quality of being worthy of honour or respect*."

**"WITH"** as a preposition means: "accompanied by (another person or thing)" or "**having or possessing (something)**." Dignity in this case...

**"IN"** also a preposition means either:

- "*inside a container, place, or area"*,
- "*surrounded or closed off by something*", or
- "*forming a part of something*"

The only way one can live "in dignity" is if one considers dignity to be a '*container*' of some sort.

While you can be "*in a state...*" of:

- undress,
- distress,
- high agitation and so on,

One can only demonstrate qualities, it is very difficult to be "in" a quality of something.  However you can **posses** the quality of dignity, or not, as the case may be.

Therefore, I would suggest that one can live '*with dignity*', by being in possession of the qualities required to be worthy of respect and honour, but one cannot literally live *within*, or *inside* those qualities and therefore, by definition, one cannot [grammatically] live within dignity, since it is a state or quality of being.